# I don't query in stored procedure because head name fields have space

Tags: sql-server, namespaces, space

In SQL Server 2008, I have a table with a column `First Name`. But this name has a space. I try query this column, but I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'First'.

How can I query this column?

Code:

```
SELECT em.First Name
FROM Emp em
```

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm found solve a problem.

```
SELECT em.[First Name]
FROM Emp em
```

It's work!! :D